# Is there a tool to see check-ins for all projects in Subversion by commit date and commit person

Tags: java, svn, version-control, plugins

I want to know If there are any plug-ins or tools to see the files commited to the subversion by date and committer.

we are using subversion. It will be nice, If its like a web app.

Please suggest If there are any other alternative ways to do this also.

Its for my manager. So cannot be through eclipse. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[websvn](http://www.websvn.info/) offers a nice access to svn via web.

It offers *RSS feed support* so your boss gets notified on every commit.

As a commercial tool [fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) might be worth a look.

Comment: This is close to what we are looking for. But, Instead of age, is there anything that sorts by date and committer?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried displaying the SVN log, using any SVN client (like TortoiseSVN, I guess your PHB is using Windows)? You can easily see the time, comments and author of any given SVN commit there...

See:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html

Since TortoiseSVN integrates nicely into Windows Explorer, even your manager should be able to use it...

That being said, it's trivial to access the log information, for example using pysvn, and displaying it in a simple GUI, if selecting and opening the revision log via the context menu is asking too much in your given use case...

Comment: I have used tortoise SVN before. Though it could solve the problem, I would like to know, if there any other tools that can make it even more easier?

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [svnmonitor](http://www.svnmonitor.com/default.shtml). It will keep checking for new changes, and notify the user (this can be configured)

Answer (score 0):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is a wiki and issue tracking system that works well with subversion. As an example, click on the project's [Browse Source](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser) link.